# While sending data by ajax, data gets lost

Tags: php, ajax, memcached

I'm working on a project where I've developed a website for a travelagency. Things are getting better and more traffic is being generated. The problem lies in slow generated pricetables. Me and my clients figured, because of the available funds, memcache should do the trick. Exited as I was to get started I've rewritten old ajax-code by new jQuery ajax code. Some other posts from this evening are a bit covering this topic.

Now I have the following code which shows a pricetable for a certain month:

```
function ShowPriceTable(targetElement, accommodationID, month)
{
    $.ajax({
        type:   "POST",
        url:    basePath + "/ajax/GetPriceTable.php",
        data:   "accommodationID="+accommodationID+"&month="+month,
        success: function(data){
            $("#"+targetElement).html(data);

            $.ajax({
                type:   "POST",
                url:    basePath + "/ajax/WriteCache.php",
                data:   "accommodationID="+accommodationID+"&month="+month+"&data="+data,
            });
        }
    });         
}
```

GetPriceTable.php is a large file, executing many queries and a lot of pricecalculation is done there. It all results in an HTML-table with prices. That output, stored in `data` is injected in the innerHTML property of a div, in this case `targetElement` because it must be adjustable.

I figured, well.. when I have the correct output in `data` I just fire another call to `WriteCache.php` with the data. The data then gets stored in the memcache server by `$cache->set("my_key", $_POST["data"]);` (headers are used and set to the past to ensure a 'new' visit for the browser).

Now comes the tricky part... no matter what I try, I only get EXACTLY 4067 characters in my cache. I've run out of options I can think of. This is only a small part of the total output... **Addition**, an `alert` of `data.length` showed me in the pricetable for the accommodation I'm looking in, the length is 98.858.

Do you have any suggestion what might be causing this strange behavior? Can it be the data is passed bit by bit? Memcache has an option `chunk_size`, by default it is set to 8192 (bytes I guess?, the [documentation](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/memcache.ini.php#ini.memcache.chunk-size) doen't tell..)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

P.s. the tag memcached must be memcache but I can't choose that option..

**Update**
The problem is irrelevant to memcache. For some reason my data get's changed while it's being sent again. This results into invalid HTML which, for some reason, is not set into the cache and not displayed in my output (mail to myself) but when I output the result (using success: in the second call) to another DIV I do see the 'mangled' output...

Comment: A collegue had a similar problem earlier last month, he was trying to send more than 1mb of data to the server via an $.ajax post and it kept failing. He had to upload in chunks of less than 1 million bytes or it would crash and not send. Maybe your error lies in a similar place?

Comment: Any thoughts on how to implement such a solution?

Comment: Just a guess but try
`data:   "accommodationID="+accommodationID+"&month="+month+"&data="+data.serialize(),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out, it took me all evening though... My output contains HTML entities. And you've guessed it. HTML entities start with an ampersand which at the same time is the delimeter-character for data retreived by `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST`. A simple `escape(data)` did the trick. Thanks for all who took the time to digg into this!

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED` in php.ini or pass it in as a flag in the set function a la `Memcache::set($key, $var, MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED);` to compress the value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After trying many things I've concluded `data` gets changed for some reason. So no matter what I'm trying to set, the result is sort of broken..